# Database-backed dictionary with arbitrary keys

Tags: python

The python shelf module only seems to be allow string keys. Is there a way to use arbitrary typed (e.g. numeric) keys? May be an sqlite-backed dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert your keys to strings? Numeric keys should be pretty easy to do this with.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize on the fly (via `pickle` or `cPickle`, like `shelve.py` does) every key, as well as every value.  It's not really worth subclassing `shelve.Shelf` since you'd have to subclass almost every method -- for once, I'd instead recommend copying `shelve.py` into your own module and editing it to suit.  That's basically like coding your new module from scratch but you get a working example to show you the structure and guidelines;-).

`sqlite` has no real advantage in a sufficiently general case (where the keys could be e.g. arbitrary tuples, of different arity and types for every entry) -- you're going to have to serialize the keys anyway to make them homogeneous.  Still, nothing stops you from using `sqlite`, e.g. to keep several "generalized shelves" into a single file (different tables of the same sqlite DB) -- if you care about performance you should measure it each way, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to overload the [] operator. You can do it by defining the `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing the `DbfilenameShelf` from the `shelve`-module. I made a shelf which automatically converts non-string-keys into string-keys and returns them in original form when queried. It works well for Python's standard immutable objects: int, float, string, tuple, boolean.

It can be found in: https://github.com/North-Guard/simple_shelve